# Prerequisites to Yang-Mills Theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation, gauge-theory

Does anyone know what prerequisite is necessary to understand Yang-Mills Theory?

And Some of the most important books necessary of the field in Math and Physic about the subject starting from the basic course.

Is knowledge of physic mandatory?

Comment: Classical YM or quantum?

Comment: I've recently read "Gauge fields, knots, and gravity" by Baez and Muniain. It presupposes some basic topology, but beyond that it is more or less self-contained introduction to classical Yang-Mills. However, some previous exposure to differential geometry would definitely be helpful.